# how to install and run wkhtmltopdf on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i recently upgraded my pc to ubuntu 22.04 but wkhtmltopdf is not working on this version of ubuntu. i use my pc to develop ruby on rails projects i tried different methods to install wkhtmltopdf but it shows an error

> Invalid platform, must be running on Ubuntu 16.04/18.04/20.04 CentOS
> 6/7/8, Debian 9/10, archlinux amd64, or intel-based Cocoa macOS
> (missing binary:

how can run wkhtmltopdf on ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps for Ubuntu 22.04

1. Run `apt install wkhtmltopdf`
2. Download DPKG file from (`https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html`) based on your architecture (amd64/arm64/ppc64el). I've given an example for amd64.
3. Run `dpkg -x wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.trusty_amd64.deb .`
4. Run `gzip --best -c usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf > wkhtmltopdf_ubuntu_22.04_amd64.gz`
5. Move `wkhtmltopdf_ubuntu_22.04_amd64.gz` to your gem installation folder. FYI - The various wkhtmltopdf-binaries will be installed here: `/usr/lib/ruby/versions/{ruby-version}/lib/ruby/gems/{ruby-version}/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-{wkhtmltopdf-binary-version}/bin/`

Comment: For person using rbenv move the gzip file into ~/.rbenv/versions/{ruby-version}/lib/ruby/gems/{ruby-version}/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin directory.

Comment: How to handle this in heroku dyno which is in production mode?